Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cryptography Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Secure degree reduction for Shamir's secret sharing

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Signature based on public key cryptography and forgery

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Certificate signature with SHA-1 and RSA: where do 1888 bits come from?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is this approach to generating a "random" number from a sha512 hash effective?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)


If PGP and GPG both follow the OpenPGP standard, are they 100% compatible in all use cases?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Choice of reduction polynomial in Whirlpool's internal cipher

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)


simple multiplication in GF(8)

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)


One-time digital signatures

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)


ASCII: weakness

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


Can passwords be stored securely so that a similarity comparison can be made?

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)


median: 1.5, mean: 1.9, stddev: 2.4698 – that's a little bit lower than last time (Dec 2013). :/

We should note that the last one of these does have good answers, it's just they're on Security.SE . Taking that into consideration you'll probably get a better set of results
